# how to set database as the source of auto-complete in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a text-box.Now i want to use auto-complete option for this textbox but i want to use the source of auto complete is my database.that is I have a database that contains 1000 words.so whenever a user enter a text into the textbox it suggests a word from the database.SO how can i use the database as the source of the auto-complete of a textbox???

Comment: Step by step tutorial: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html

Comment: do you even try to search on google or on stackoverflow??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AutoCompleteStringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletestringcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and populate it with strings from your database:

```
var autoCompleteData = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
autoCompleteData.add("SomeString1"); // Can be strings retrieved from database
autoCompleteData.add("SomeString2"); // Can be strings retrieved from database

textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteData;
```